# How can I concatenate many column vectors into one matrix?

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I want to concatenate 100 column vectors into one matrix. The code is the following:

```
for i = 1:100
X = mean(TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput(1:200, 25:35), 2);
end
```

What I want is to concatenate all 100 column vectors (each 200x1 length vectors) into one matrix (which should become a 200x100 matrix). I tried to use `C = cat(2,X(:))`, but it didn't work. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: Use `X(:,i) = mean(..`

Answer (score 1):

Just pre-allocate X with your desired 200x100 size and then index into columns of `X` appropriately in your loop. I.e.,

```
X = zeros(200, 100);

for i = 1:100
    X(:,i) = mean(TMP(i).SonarReturnData.BeamsOutput(1:200, 25:35), 2);
end
```

Comment: X(200,100) = 0; could be a faster alternative to pre-allocate [Source](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance). +1 for efforts

Comment: Ahh that's interesting; didn't realize that! Thanks for the source.